# Reject forged emails with spamassassin from own email address

Tags: email, spam-prevention, spamassassin

Lately I've been receiving ~10 emails per day from myself. It's my own domain hosted on my own server (at home). I'm running openpanel and spamassassin. How can I configure spamassassin to block such emails? (Sent to myself).

The content of the mail is about a new registration on a Joomla! site. It doesn't say what Joomla! site, just Joomla!:

```
Hello Administrator,

A new user has registered at Joomla!.
This e-mail contains their details:

Name: MahinoEyob1
E-mail: kir****ir@hotmail.com
Username: Mah*****ob1

Please do not respond to this message. It is automatically generated and is for 
information purposes only.
```

I'm running ubuntu 12.4 and postfix

Comment: Are you on a shared server?

Comment: No, like I said, it's my OWN personal server, just chilling in my appartment

Comment: I assume you don't have a Joomla installation on said server?  Are you sure the email is actually being forged?

Comment: I checked, I don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact your ISP and tell them you would like to add an SPF record to your DNS records.  SPF or Sender Framework Policy in short sets an IP, or list of IPsas authorized email distributors for your domain.  Sender Policy Framework (SPF) is an email validation system designed to prevent email spam by detecting email spoofing, a common vulnerability, by verifying sender IP addresses. SPF allows administrators to specify which hosts are allowed to send mail from a given domain by creating a specific SPF record (or TXT record) in the Domain Name System (DNS). Mail exchangers use the DNS to check that mail from a given domain is being sent by a host sanctioned by that domain's administrators.

Sender Policy Framework is defined in IETF publication RFC 4408
[Wikipedia Full Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)